# ConnexionRefusedError : [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I'm working on a robotics assignment where we are creating a RPC module for our project. So I have a client module agent_client.py and a server module agent_server.py. For this we use the xmlrpc library. In the client program, when I try to do a remote procedure call through the server proxy of xmlprc (saved in attribute self.s) it throws me a ConnexionRefusedError :  [WinError 10061] error.

Here is the code for agent_client.py (PS a big part of the code is already provided in the assignment. I put the imports and the parts with YOUR CODE HERE)

```
import weakref
import xmlrpc.client
from time import sleep
from numpy.matlib import identity
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
import sys
sys.path.append('../joint_control')


class PostHandler(object):
    '''the post hander wraps function to be executed in parallel
    '''
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.proxy = weakref.proxy(obj)

    def execute_keyframes(self, keyframes):
        '''non-blocking call of ClientAgent.execute_keyframes'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        process = Thread(target=self.proxy.execute_keyframes, args=[keyframes])  
        process.start()                                                        

    def set_transform(self, effector_name, transform):
        '''non-blocking call of ClientAgent.set_transform'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        process = Thread(target=self.proxy.set_transform, args=[effector_name, transform])
        process.start()


class ClientAgent(object):
    '''ClientAgent request RPC service from remote server
    '''
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    def __init__(self):
        self.post = PostHandler(self)
        self.s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://localhost:9999') #le serveur est local (dans notre ordinateur) -> pas besoin de connection à internet  
        

    def get_angle(self, joint_name):
        '''get sensor value of given joint'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        return self.s.get_angle(joint_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    agent = ClientAgent()
    # YOUR TEST CODE HERE    
    print(agent.get_angle("RKneePitch"))
```

Here is the code for agent_server.py

```
# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

class ServerAgent(InverseKinematicsAgent):
    '''ServerAgent provides RPC service
    '''
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServerAgent, self).__init__()
        
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 9999), logRequests=True)  
        print("Listening on localhost:9999")
        server.register_instance(self)  
        server.register_introspection_functions()  
        server.register_multicall_functions()      

        thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)  
        print("Server thread started")
    
    def get_angle(self, joint_name):
        '''get sensor value of given joint'''
        # YOUR CODE HERE 
        angle = self.perception.joint[joint_name]
        return joint_name + " angle = " + str("%.2f" % angle)
```

I don't know what to do. The error points to the line `return self.s.get_angle(joint_name)`. Thinking it may have to do with which port to use, I have tried (a bit randomly) a few ports like localhost 6666 or localhost 6789

EDIT : when I change the port from 'http://localhost:9999' to ''http://0.0.0.0:4711'' I get a slightly different error : WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context
I don't know if it's useful information.

Comment: @ray done it now